# Reusing patch objects in matplotlib without them moving position

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib, patch, figure

I want to automatically generate a series of plots which are clipped to patches. If I try and reuse a patch object, it moves position across the canvas.

This script (based on an answer to a previous question by Yann) demonstrates what is happening.

```
import pylab as plt
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.patches as patches

sp.random.seed(100)
x = sp.random.random(100)
y = sp.random.random(100)
patch = patches.Circle((.75,.75),radius=.25,fc='none')


def doplot(x,y,patch,count):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    im = ax.scatter(x,y)
    ax.add_patch(patch)
    im.set_clip_path(patch)
    plt.savefig(str(count) + '.png')


for count in xrange(4):
    doplot(x,y,patch,count)
```

The first plot looks like this:[image: Correct position of patch - first time plotted]

But in the second '1.png', the patch has moved.. 
[image: Wrong position of the patch]

However replotting again doesn't move the patch.  '2.png' and '3.png' look exactly the same as '1.png'.

Could anyone point me in the right direction of what I'm doing wrong??

In reality, the patches I'm using are relatively complex and take some time to generate - I'd prefer to not have to remake them every frame if possible.

Comment: The really bizzare part is that this only happens if you call `savefig`, and not if you call `show`...

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be avoided by using the same axes for each plot, with `ax.cla()` called to clear the plot after each iteration.

```
import pylab as plt
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.patches as patches

sp.random.seed(100)
patch = patches.Circle((.75,.75),radius=.25,fc='none')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

def doplot(x,y,patch,count):
    ax.set_xlim(-0.2,1.2)
    ax.set_ylim(-0.2,1.2)
    x = sp.random.random(100)
    y = sp.random.random(100)
    im = ax.scatter(x,y)
    ax.add_patch(patch)
    im.set_clip_path(patch)
    plt.savefig(str(count) + '.png')
    ax.cla()

for count in xrange(4):
    doplot(x,y,patch,count)
```

Comment: Great; glad I could help! Please do not accept this answer, as I'd like to know why the patch is transformed in your original code too.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to unutbu's answer, is to use the `copy` package, which can copy objects. It is very hard to see how things are changing after one calls `add_patch`, but they are. The `axes`, `figure`, `extents`,`clip_box`,`transform` and `window_extent` properties of the patch are changed. Unfortantely the superficial printing of each of these properties results in the same string, so it looks like they are not changing. But the underlying attributes of some or all of these properties, eg  `extents` is a `Bbox`, are probably changed.

The copy call will allow you to get a unique patch for each figure you make, without know what kind of patch it is. This still does not answer why this happens, but as I wrote above it's an alternative solution to the problem:

```
import copy 

def doplot(x,y,patch,count):
    newPatch = copy.copy(patch)
    fig = plt.figure(dpi=50)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    im = ax.scatter(x,y)
    ax.add_patch(newPatch)
    im.set_clip_path(newPatch)
    plt.savefig(str(count) + '.png')
```

Also you can use `fig.savefig(str(count) + '.png')`. This explicitly saves the figure `fig` where as the `plt.savefig` call saves the current figure, which happens to be the one you want.